How does one "emergency extend" the right main landing gear of a B-52 Stratofortress?
In an April 11, 2024 video an embedded CNN crew documents a 33 hour B-52 Stratofortress round trip flight between Barksdale Air Force Base in Louisiana "flying near Russia, China, North Korea, and back."
At one point Engine #5 had an issue and was shut down.
Near the end of the video after 05:00 there is an exchange on audio, shown in captions:

One gear not down?
Affirm. Right main gear is not down.
Go ahead and emergency extend it.

Question: How does one "emergency extend" the right main landing gear of a B-52 Stratofortress?
I'm probably remembering some old black-and-white WWII movie seen on Saturday morning TV when I was young, but I'm imagining the flight engineer going to the back of the plane, lifting up a floorboard and revealing a big hand crank and struggling to extend the landing gear manually. Finally a mechanical indicator in the cockpit pops up confirming successful extension and lock (or not, enhancing the drama of the movie?)
I have a hunch that modern B-52's have a more automated and powered procedure for emergency extension.

 
click for full size

Many planes have/had an emergency landing gear extension mode that just releases the locks and lets gravity do the rest of the work.

After running through the usual series of checks (cycling the circuit breakers, etc), one takes the Landing Gear Emergency switch for the gear in question to EXTEND.
Reference - B52 Pilot's Manual page 367 (pdf page number)
Note: This manual is for the C/D model B52s, but my vague memory from working on the G/H model simulators in the 80s is that it worked the same way there.
Here is a schematic of the landing gear system showing the switches and the backup hydraulic system connections actuated by them.

Reference: The B-52 Stratofortress: A Case Study (partial document) (pdf page 10)
This document covers the H model aircraft so I'm more confident the answer applies now.

I see, it looks like it activates a backup/redundant hydraulic circuit - there's no manual cranking involved.

@uhoh If you want fun stuff under the floorboards, see the 737. For manual cranking a big handle, that's the A320.
